# (PHS) Password Hash Synchronization in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-pipelines, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there a way to retrive all the users who are enrolled in PHS (password hash synchronization) using Graph API or some other.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of below command , we can find out whether Password Hash Synchronization is enabled for the Azure AD Users:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/tshoot-connect-password-hash-synchronization#run-the-diagnostics-cmdlet-2

```
Invoke-ADSyncDiagnostics -PasswordSync
```

You can also check this document for troubleshooting task: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/tshoot-connect-password-hash-synchronization#understand-the-results-of-the-troubleshooting-task